# Open popup when I click on third party URL

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to build external popup code with jQuery. I have used below code to do the same.

The problem is if I have not added specified class **external** to the anchor it will not open the popup.

Is there any alternative for the below or trick to do this?

```js
$("a").on('click', function (e) {
    if ($(this).hasClass('external')) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var href_val = $(this).attr('href');
        $('.popupHolder').show();
        $('.popupHolder h3 span').html(href_val);
    }
});
$("button.proceed").on('click', function (e) {
    window.location.href = $('.popupHolder h3 span').html();
});
$("button.cancel").on('click', function (e) {
    $('.popupHolder').hide();
});
```

```css
.popupHolder {
    display: none;
    position:fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
    <h1 id="back">Home</h1>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
        standard
        dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type
        specimen
        book. <a class="external" href="https://www.google.com/">Google.com</a> <a href="#about">Hash Link About</a>
    </p>
</div>
<div class="content">
    <h2 id="about">About</h2>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the <a class="external" href="https://www.facebook.com/">Facebook.com</a>
        printing and
        typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
        standard
        <a href="#back">Back to Top</a>
    </p>
</div>
<div class="content">
    <p><a href="https://www.twitter.com/">Twitter.com</a>
        <a href="#back">Back to Top</a>
    </p>
</div>
<div class="popupHolder">
    <h3>Do you want to visit <span></span>?</h3>
    <button class="proceed">Proceed</button>
    <button class="cancel">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you need to check the current **href** value is with same host. If that so then it will show the popup as per required.

Else it will show directly opens the url without appearing the popup.

#### Try below Code

```js
$(document).on('click', 'a', function (e) {
    var a_id = $(this).attr('id');
    var href_val = $(this).attr('href');

    if (href_val[0] != '#' && href_val != undefined) {
        var j = href_val.indexOf("://");
        var host = "";
        for (i = j + 3; i < href_val.length; i++) {
            if (href_val.charAt(i) != '/') {
                host = host + "" + href_val.charAt(i);
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
        var my_url = window.location.hostname;
        if (my_url != host) {
            if (a_id == undefined) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var href_val = $(this).attr('href');
                $('.popupHolder').show();
                $('.popupHolder h3 span').html(href_val);
            }
        }
    }
});
$("button.proceed").on('click', function (e) {
    window.location.href = $('.popupHolder h3 span').html();
});
$("button.cancel").on('click', function (e) {
    $('.popupHolder').hide();
});
```

```css
.popupHolder {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
    <h1 id="back">Home</h1>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
        standard
        dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type
        specimen
        book. <a class="external" href="https://www.google.com/">Google.com</a> <a href="#about">Hash Link About</a>
    </p>
</div>
<div class="content">
    <h2 id="about">About</h2>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the <a class="external" href="https://www.facebook.com/">Facebook.com</a>
        printing and
        typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
        standard
        <a href="#back">Back to Top</a>
    </p>
</div>
<div class="content">
    <p><a href="https://www.twitter.com/">Twitter.com</a>
        <a href="#back">Back to Top</a>
    </p>
</div>
<div class="popupHolder">
    <h3>Do you want to visit <span></span>?</h3>
    <button class="proceed">Proceed</button>
    <button class="cancel">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Mahesh Thorat it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You have added the condition in the script that if element has `external` class then only popup will be shown
just remove that condition

```
$("a").on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var href_val = $(this).attr('href');
        $('.popupHolder').show();
        $('.popupHolder h3 span').html(href_val);
 
});
$("button.proceed").on('click', function (e) {
    window.location.href = $('.popupHolder h3 span').html();
});
$("button.cancel").on('click', function (e) {
    $('.popupHolder').hide();
});
```

Comment: This will however open *all* links in the page as a popup, which is certainly not desired.